# Build fails after updating to gradle 3.3

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I just updated my JavaFX project from gradle 3.1 to 3.3. Now the build fails with the following error:

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspath(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/List;

I'm using the javafx-gradle-plugin and this is where it fails. I read about adding a @Classpath annotation to my classpath dependency, but I can't find any documentation about this.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.7.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '4.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.hid4java', name: 'hid4java', version: '0.4.0'
}


apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'


jfx {
    verbose = true
    bundler = "exe"

    mainClass = 'xxx.xxx'

    allPermissions = true

    appName = "xxx"

    vendor = 'xxx'
}
```

As I said it worked before, but now something with the classpath seems to be wrong. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would check what the gradle folks have to say. You might find help here; but I am sure that they have users forums too; and that people there would also be interested in learning about such bugs.

Comment: Maybe a stacktrace may help. run the same task using `--stacktrace`

Answer (score 2):

I should have checked the issue page on the javafx-gradle-plugin github page. This is a known issue and will be fixed in future versions. Thanks @dwursteisen for pointing out the --stacktrace option. With the --stacktrace I figured out that it was a plugin issue, and not an issue with gradle itself.

Comment: Hi there, I'm the author of that gradle-plugin. This is a know bug, I used some "internal" class, which got removed in gradle 3.3 ... workaround is to use some version before 3.3, but I'm on it ;)

Comment: Just to make some cross-reference here, this is the corresponding reported issue: https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/52